# resize movie to rectangular of 200x200

Tags: ffmpeg, resize

How would one resize to 200x200 rectangular movie ?

I tried several suggestions all fail like:

```
ffmpeg -i 001.mov -vf "scale=-1:360" 001.mp4
```

But this does not make it rectangular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: original] [image]
<sub>Original (320x240) and scaled (200x200) image examples.</sub>

You can force to a specific output size using the [`scale`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) video filter.

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf scale=200:200 -codec:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 \
-codec:a copy output.mp4
```

Note that ffmpeg may stretch or squish the output to match your forced output size.
In this example the audio was [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy). This simply re-muxes the audio and therefore avoids re-encoding and potential quality loss.

**Also see:**

- [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)